# Passing SQL query result as Parameter for sending Email using Perl

Tags: sql, perl, email

I want to retrieve the email address from the table and using that to send email using perl script.

How to use the query result in mail.
I am new to perl scripting please help.

I have updated as suggested but still there are some issues.
Please tell me where I am going wrong.

Thanks in advance.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# $Id: outofstockmail.pl,v 1.0 2012/03/01 21:35:24 isha Exp $

require '/usr/home/fnmugly/main.cfg';

use DBI;
my $dbh = DBI->connect($CFG{'mysql_dsn'},$CFG{'mysql_user'},
                       $CFG{'mysql_password'})
    or &PrintError("Could not connect to the MySQL Database.\nFile could not be made!\n");
$dbh->{RaiseError} = 1;        # save having to check each method call

print "<H1>Hello World</H1>\n";

$sql = "Select OS.name, OS.customer_email, OS.product, OS.salesperson,  
               OS.salesperson_email
        from   products AS P
        LEFT JOIN outofstock_sku AS OS ON OS.product = P.sku
        LEFT JOIN tech4less.inventory AS I ON (I.sku = P.sku AND I.status = 'A')
        WHERE mail_sent='0'
        GROUP BY OS.product";

#$sth = $dbh->do($sql);

my $sth1 = $dbh->prepare($sql);

$sth1->execute; 

while ( my @row = $sth1->fetchrow_array ) {   

    # email
    open MAIL, "| $mail_prog -t" || die "Could not connect to sendmail.";
    print MAIL "To: $row[1]"; 
    print MAIL "From: $row[4]";
    print MAIL "Reply-To:$row[4]";
    print MAIL "CC: $row[4]";  
    print MAIL "Subject: Product requested is back in inventory\n";
    print MAIL "\n";
    print MAIL "Hi $row[0] , The product $row[2] is available in the stock.\n";
    print MAIL "\n";
    close MAIL;

    $sql = "Update outofstock_sku SET mail_sent='0' WHERE mail_sent='1'";
    $sth2 = $dbh->do($sql);
}               

$sth = $dbh->do($sql);

$dbh->disconnect();

exit;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
require '/main.cfg';

# use DBI interface for MySQL
            use DBI;

            # connect to MySQL

            $dbh = DBI->connect($CFG{'mysql_dsn'},$CFG{'mysql_user'},$CFG{'mysql_password'}) or
                    &PrintError("Could not connect to the MySQL Database.\nFile could not be made!\n");
            $dbh->{RaiseError} = 1;        # save having to check each method call

            $mailprog = $CFG{'mail_prog'};

            $sql = "Select OS.name,OS.customer_email,OS.product,OS.salesperson_email from products AS P LEFT JOIN outofstock_sku AS OS ON OS.product = P.sku LEFT JOIN inventory AS I ON (I.sku = P.sku AND I.status = 'A') WHERE mail_sent='0' GROUP BY OS.product";

            $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);

            $sth->execute();
                while($ref = $sth->fetchrow_hashref()) 
                        {

                            open MAIL, "| $mailprog -f sssss\@gmail.com -t" || die "Could not connect to sendmail.";
                            print "Content-Type: text/html\n\n";
                            print MAIL "To: $ref->{'customer_email'}\n";
                            print MAIL "From: \"\" <wwwwwwwwww\n>";
                            #   print MAIL "From: \"\" <$ref->{'salesperson_email'}\n>";
                            print MAIL "Reply-To: ";
                            #   print MAIL "CC: $ref->{'salesperson_email'}\n";
                            print MAIL "Subject:#$ref->{'product'}\n";
                            print MAIL "Hi $ref->{'name'},\nThe product $ref->{'product'} is available in the stock.\n";
                            close MAIL;

                                                        }


            $sth->finish();

            # Close MySQL connection
            $dbh->disconnect();
            exit;
```

Answer (score 2):

This script has too many problems to address question specifically:

1) Use `use strict; use warnings;`. It will help you to be more accurate.

2) `DBI->connect()` takes options as last argument, so you can set RaiseError there:

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $pwd, { RaiseError => 1 });
```

3) `$dbh->do` doesn't return sth object. You need prepare and execute:

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute;
while ( my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array ) {
    ...
    print MAIL "Hi $row[0]. We're happy to ... $row[1]...\n";
    ...
}
```

4) To send mail use a module, for example [Email::Sender::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/Email-Sender-0.110003/lib/Email/Sender/Manual/QuickStart.pm).

Comment: Thanks but the mail issue is to send mail using results of sql query

Answer (score 0):

Scary to think how much old code like this is still in use out there.

You don't actually say what your question is. Just saying that the code has "some issues" doesn't really help us to help you.

Some suggestions...

1. Use `strict` and `warnings`
2. Pass `RaiseError` as an argument to the `connect` call
3. Print out the contents of @row so you can be sure that the SQL is correct
4. Use [Email::Simple](https://metacpan.org/module/Email%3a%3aSimple) to create your email and [Email::Sender](https://metacpan.org/module/Email%3a%3aSender) to send it
5. (Far less important) Consider using [DBIx::Class](https://metacpan.org/module/DBix%3a%3aClass) to talk to the database